# $LU$ Factorization, improving upon stability

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I was wondering when we add partial pivoting to an $LU$ factorization to a matrix $A$ it supposedly changes the data structure but improves the overall algorithm since we get better numerical stability. I am curious to why this is?

Any feedback is appreciated, my apologies for not formally introducing the maths involved but I was more for hoping a qualitative explanation, not to say quantitative is not appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the operation which we do by hand, i.e. an in-place implemention of Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting which overwrites the matrix $A$ with the LU factorization.

If a pivot is small, then the linear update of the lower right hand submatrix will almost certainly be done with some componentwise errors which are large in magnitude. This pushes the components of the computed factors $\hat{L}$ and $\hat{U}$ far away from their correct values.

The ultimate goal of the factorization is to solve linear system cheaply. We the solve the upper and lower triangular system with a small componentwise backward error, but if the factors have already been corrupted, then is all for naught.

This is by no means a complete answer. Notice that the product of the pivots (the diagonal entries of U) is equal to the determinant of the matrix, so selecting a small pivot may ultimately be unavoidable. In this case, we would prefer to do it at end of the factorization process where the impact is minimal, than corrupt the entire matrix.

This question also touches upon a central theme in numerical analysis. If an algorithm breaks in arithmetic under certain conditions, then the near occurance of these conditions are typically fatal for an implementation in floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm for $LU$ factorization of a matrix $A$ (at least, the only one that I'm aware of) involves dividing several elements in $A$ by $a_{11}$. Without pivoting, this element might be equal to 0, and we obviously can't have that. In addition, this element might be very small, and dividing by very small numbers in 32- or 64-bit floating point arithmetic can lead to numerical instability. To get around this, we add partial pivoting to place the largest element in the 1st column in the $(1, 1)$ position of A.